# AdMob Não aparecem anúncios

Tags: android, admob

Fiz tudo certinho: vinculei o app com o firebase, só que na hora de executar a área do anúncio fica branco. Agora, se eu usar o unit id de testes ele funciona normalmente

Código do MainActivity

```
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Código do layout

```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Strings

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-
 1770401303076452/1027518523</string>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Você tem que esperar cerca de algumas horas para que o anúncio seja exibido.

Comment: Obrigado , pensei que tivesse feito algo errado

Comment: Você adicionou em um RelativeLayout?

Comment: Agora ele apareceu normal , só que o contador de clicks do site do admob não sai do 0

Comment: Você sabe que de acordo as políticas o dveloper não pode ficar clicando nos banners né?! E outra, os cliques não são computados na hora, da mesma forma que o banner também não é mostrado na hora que você cria um campanha.

Comment: Estava fazendo só um teste pra saber se deu tudo certo , obrigado amigo!

Comment: O que mostra no log? Quando executa o log instrui você a adicionar o device como um ID de teste no builder, assim você vê um anúncio de teste que costuma aparecer mais depressa que o anúncio de verdade, o que vai resolver mais rápido sua dúvida.

Comment: Paiva, alguma resposta resolveu seu problema? Teria algo a mais que possamos explicar?

Answer (score 1):

> só que na hora de executar a área do anúncio fica branco

Teste diretamente no aparelho ou para testar com os emuladores, pode tentar desta forma:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
```

> Agora ele apareceu normal , só que o contador de clicks do site do
>   admob não sai do 0

Geralmente irá atualizar no próximo dia. Ele não é bem em tempo real como o Google Analytics.

> AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

Por essa linha, acredito que seu Android Studio esteja desatualizado, pois não há mais necessidade de fazer o `cast` mais.
Tente sempre manter atualizada sua IDE porque as vezes alguns erros já se resolvem só com isso.

Answer (score 0):

Se vc acabou de criar o anúncio no admob, demora um tempo para o anúncio começar a ser exibido. E se vc estiver usando emulador do android studio, só vai aparecer anúncio de teste, mesmo vc usando anúncio normal.